# Pure CSS hover resulting in a color-overlay with text

Tags: html, css, hover, fluid-layout

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, but I've been finding answers on here for years. This is one I can't seem to find though.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do the following using only HTML and CSS.

I have a fluid layout, and I want to keep the images fluid. I currently have each image set up to fill their respective divs by using the max-height:100% and max-width:100% properties.

On hover, I would like the image to have a slightly transparent color overlay, and reveal some text and a button.

I'm able to do this if I define the image/div width, but I cannot figure out how to do it while keeping the image so it re-sizes dynamically.

**[Here's a Fiddle of 4 images in a fluid layout.](http://jsfiddle.net/polarpanda/HGWPZ/)** Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, I feel like I'm overlooking something.

And the code:

`HTML`

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="span4 red">
            <img src="http://img.thesun.co.uk/aidemitlum/archive/01500/SNE0125Q---_149991_1500286a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="span4 blue">
            <img src="http://img.thesun.co.uk/aidemitlum/archive/01500/SNE0125Q---_149991_1500286a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="span4 green">
            <img src="http://img.thesun.co.uk/aidemitlum/archive/01500/SNE0125Q---_149991_1500286a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="span4 purple">
            <img src="http://img.thesun.co.uk/aidemitlum/archive/01500/SNE0125Q---_149991_1500286a.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

`CSS`

```
body { margin:0;}
#container { width:100%; font-size:0;}
img { max-width:100%; max-height:100%;}
.span4 { width:25%; display:block;}
.red { background-color: red; float:left; overflow:hidden;}
.blue { background-color: blue; float:left; overflow:hidden;}
.green { background-color: green; float:left; overflow:hidden;}
.purple { background-color: purple; float:left; overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzp7P/)

**html**

```
<div class="span4 red">
    <img src="http://img.thesun.co.uk/aidemitlum/archive/01500/SNE0125Q---_149991_1500286a.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
        <span>Text text text</span>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.span4 {
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    position:relative; /*added*/
}

/*added*/
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display:none;
}
.red:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: You have `font-size:0` set on `#container` by the way that's why the text is showing up.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something I was missing. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `:after` pseudo selector ([note browser compatability](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent))

http://jsfiddle.net/HGWPZ/1/

```
.span4 {
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
}

.span4:hover:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}

.red:hover:after
{
    background: RGBA(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

.blue:hover:after
{
    background: RGBA(0, 0, 255, .3);
}

.green:hover:after
{
    background: RGBA(0, 255, 0, .3);
}

.purple:hover:after
{
    background: RGBA(230, 230, 250, .3);
}
```

idk what the RGB value for purple is though :p so play around with it

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I didn't even think about pseudo classes. Is there a way to style the content "" of the :before and :after?

Comment: Sure. Just apply styles like you regularly would to the `:after` selector. I'd try and avoid using CSS for any actual content though - content should generally be in your markup.